# Condition for basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$S=\{a+ib,c+id\}$ is the basis for vector space $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ iff

$a) \ ad-bc=0\\ b)\ ad+bc=0\\c)\ ad+bc \neq 0 \\ d)\ ad-bc \neq 0$

I'm thinking $d)$. Am I right? If yes, please give me reason why so?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you thinking $D$?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking $d)$. Am I right? If yes, please give me reason why so?
>   Thanks.

You are right, but is it just a guess or what is your reasoning?

**Hint**: you want $a+bi$ and $c+di$ to be linearly independent, which means they cannot be scalar multiples. What happens if they *are* scalar multiples? Then for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, you have:
$$\left( a+bi \right) = k \left( c+di \right) \iff \ldots $$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially asking for the conditions under which $S=\{(a,b), (c,d)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$. Recall that an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if its columns form a basis for $\mathbb R^n$. Such a matrix is also invertible if and only if it has nonzero determinant. So, let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a\,\,\,\, c \\ b \,\,\,\,d \end{bmatrix}$$
Based on the above, $S$ is a basis if and only if $\det A = ad-bc\neq 0$.